# Customizing tables in Stata

Tags: file-io, output, regression, stata, linear-regression

Using `Stata14` on windows, I am wondering how to build customized tables from several regression results. Here is an example. We have

```
reg y, x1
predict resid1, residuals
summarize resid1
```

Which gives:

```
    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
      resid1 |  5,708,529    4.83e-11    .7039736  -3.057633   3.256382
```

And run another regrerssion and similarly obtain the residuals:

```
reg y, x2
predict resid2, residuals
```

I would like to create a table which has the two standard deviations of the two residuals, and optimally output it to `latex`. I am familiar with the `esttab` and `estout` commands for outputting regression results to `latex`, but these do not work for customized tables as in the above example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `estpost`. This should get you started.

```
sysuse auto, clear
regress price weight
predict error1, residuals
regress price trunk
predict error2, residuals

eststo clear
estpost summarize error1 error2
eststo
esttab, cells("count mean sd min max") noobs nonum
esttab using so.tex, cells("count mean sd min max") noobs nonum replace
```

More [here](http://repec.org/bocode/e/estout/estpost.html#estpost101).