# Customized table with multiple columns

Tags: latex, stata

I am using the *community-contributed* command [`estout`](http://repec.org/bocode/e/estout/) to output a customized table from Stata to a latex `.tex` file. However, I do not know how I can add multiple columns in one table.

Below is a simplified example where I create two separate tables, each containing the standard deviations of the residuals from two different regressions:

```
reg y x1
predict res1, residual
reg y x2
predict res2, residual
reg y x3
predict res3, residual
reg y x4
predict res4, residual

eststo clear
estpost summarize res1 res2
eststo
esttab, cells("sd") noobs nonum
esttab using first.tex, cells("sd") noobs nonum replace

eststo clear
estpost summarize res3 res4
eststo
esttab, cells("sd") noobs nonum
esttab using second.tex, cells("sd") noobs nonum replace
```

However, I would like to have the two columns in the same table as follows:

```
sd(res1)   sd(res3)
sd(res2)   sd(res4)
```

Is Stata 14 capable of customizing a table like this?

---

This question is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43166930/customizing-tables-in-stata) question in that there I was looking for the command which creates customized tables. The answer was `estpost`. Now, I am asking for customization of this command in a way that I couldn't find in its documentation.

Comment: Cross-reference to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43166930/customizing-tables-in-stata explaining what is different would do no harm.

Comment: Thanks @NickCox, I will add an edit to explain the difference.

Comment: Thank you @PearlySpencer, I have been away and just now saw it. It's perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a matrix with the results and then configure `estout`'s options accordingly:

```
sysuse auto, clear

regress price mpg
predict res1, residual

regress price length
predict res2, residual

regress price displacement
predict res3, residual

regress price headroom
predict res4, residual

matrix A = J(2, 2, 0)
local j = 0

forvalues i = 1 / 4 {
     summarize res`i'
     if `i' <= 2 matrix A[`i', 1] = r(sd)
     else {
         local ++j
         matrix A[`j', 2] = r(sd)
    }
}

esttab matrix(A), mlabels(sd) collabels(none) coeflabels(none)

--------------------------------------
                       sd             
--------------------------------------
                 2605.621     2562.891
                 2660.311     2930.096
--------------------------------------
```